# Scala Play 2 Guice dependency injection with traits

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice

In my application I have the following traits/concrete classes:

In package `models.daos`:

```
trait UserDAO // UserDAO.scala
class UserDAOImpl @Inject() (app: play.api.Appliction) extends UserDAO // UserDAOImpl.scala
```

In package `controllers`:

```
class Application @Inject() (userDao: UserDAO) extends Controller
```

However, when I run the app I get:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for models.daos.UserDAO was bound.
  while locating models.daos.UserDAO
    for parameter 0 at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:15)
  while locating controllers.Application
    for parameter 1 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:31)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
```

I'm new to dependency injection and don't really know how to tell Guice to use the concrete class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to extend AbstractModule

```
class DaoModule extends AbstractModule {
  def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[UserDAO])
     .to(classOf[UserDAOImpl])
  }
}
```

in `conf/application.conf` you need to add:

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.DaoModule"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create injector somewhere in your code, typically in Global object of your Play module:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  val injector = Guice.createInjector(
    new AbstractModule {
      protected def configure() = {
        bind(classOf[UserDAO]).to(classOf[UserDAOImpl])
      }
    }
  )
  ...
}
```

Comment: This gives me a "Cannot init Global object" exception. I changed it to `lazy val` and this error goes away, but it doesn't have any effect (still the original error). If I use the `@ImplementedBy(classOf[UserDAOImpl])` annotation on the `UserDAO` trait then everything works well, but that kindof defeats the purpose of injection... I'm using Play 2.4.

Comment: Setting the bindings in `Global` object is now deprecated. The recommended way to programmatically bind dependencies is using modules. Thanks!